# Unkown Column error on django admin, how to fix it?

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have an error in my django admin:

**(1054, "Unknown column 'flora2estado.id' in 'field list'")**

the model flora2estado has two fields, they are used in unique together as a pseudo composite key, how can i fix this?

admin.py
`admin.site.register(Flora2Estado)`

models.py

```
    estado = models.OneToOneField(Estados, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    especie_id = models.IntegerField()
    flora2estado = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flora2estado'
        unique_together = (('estado', 'especie_id'),)
```

I tried to add the "flora2estado" field without sucess.

All migrations done, thank you for your time

Comment: Please show the entire model.

Answer (score 2):

Django is trying to select `id` field, as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

> By default, Django gives each model the following field:
>
> ```
> id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
> ```
>
> **If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, specify**
> **primary_key=True on one of your fields.** If Django sees you’ve
> explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id
> column.

Comment: you should still keep id to act out as id in this case considering Django does not support composite primary keys

Comment: hello, i did what you said, now i'm getting this error :
MultipleObjectsReturned at /admin/accounts/flora2estado/99/change/
get() returned more than one Flora2Estado -- it returned 5!

Comment: this seems to be follow up question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions